# Solving a SQL query involving set division by another method

Tags: sql, mysql-5.6

The problem statement for the SQL query is to find all the pilots who can fly the planes listed in the Plane table. So basically we have a Pilot table which has 2 columns namely Pilot Names and the Planes they can fly and the second table called the Plane table which has only 1 column namely the Planes column. So, we have to find all the pilots that can fly all the planes listed in the Plane column of the Plane table. I know one of the ways is to proceed via relational division but is there any other way to solve this?
The Table Schema loos like this:
Pilot(Pilot_Name, Planes)
Plane(Planes)
That shows the Pilot table consists of 2 columns and the Plane table consist of a single column.
The below code is the solution to the problem using set divison:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pilot_name
 FROM PilotSkills AS PS1 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
      FROM Hangar
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
              FROM PilotSkills AS PS2
             WHERE (PS1.pilot_name = PS2.pilot_name)
               AND (PS2.plane_name = Hangar.plane_name)));
```

This query gives the desired result. But I was wondering if there is another method to solve this question without using the above mentioned concept of set division.

Comment: You title, you question and your code don't seems properly .. related  .. show a proper bd schema and sample data for understand your need

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using aggregation:

```
select pilot_name
from pilotskills
group by pilot_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from planes);
```

If a plan could be listed twice in for a given pilot in the skills table, the `having` clause should be:

```
select pilot_name
from pilotskills
group by pilot_name
having count(distinct plane_name) = (select count(*) from planes);
```

Comment: The Planes can be listed more than one time in the pilotskills table as multiple pilots can fly the same planes but for one pilot there are no duplicate values of the same plane

Comment: I tried your query Gordon it does not give the desired result. It is only showing the name of the first pilot irrespective of the plane names listed in the Planes table

Comment: @RAGHAV . . . Are you sure you have the `group by`?